# How to stay focused on Textbox when Barcode is scanned in Windows Forms Application?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have a [Snap 3100](http://autoidindonesia.com/brochures/snap_brochure/3100_brochure.pdf) series USB Linear Barcode Scanner Gun. It works as keyboard wedge by capturing data from barcode image and returns the value.

I wrote the program to auto-focus and display the scanned value in Textbox. But it loses its focus when users do other functions and they have to put the cursor back to Textbox to get the value. This is POS System and I don't want the operators to use a mouse when focus is lost.

I tried using both:

`textbox1.Focus();` and

`this.ActiveControl = textbox1;`

but not working.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

`NOTE:`
In web application, I would use JQuery to handle this problem. I need something like this in Winforms.

```
$(function() {
 // Focus on load
 $('.scanner').focus();
 // Force focus
 $('.scanner').focusout(function(){
     $('.scanner').focus();
 });
 // Ajax Stuff
 $('.scanner').change(function() {
     $.ajax({
         async: true,
         cache: false,
         type: 'post',
         url: '/echo/html/',
         data: {
             html: '<p>This is your object successfully loaded here.</p>'
         },
         dataType: 'html',
         beforeSend: function() {
             window.alert('Scanning code');
         },
         success: function(data) {
             window.alert('Success');
             $('.objectWrapper').append(data);
         },
         // Focus
         complete: function() {
             $('.scanner').val('').focus();
         }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: You say you tried `Focus()` already.  Did you find a barcode scan event to hook into already?

Comment: You said **But it loses its focus when users do other functions**. so user do other function on the same application or any other application ?

Comment: I would suggest to define one shortcut key like **Ctrl + Shift + s** (Indicating start scan) and on execution of this shortcut you can set the focus on your textbox.

Comment: @SpiderCode Users do the other functions on the same form. Is there any other approach without using shortcut key?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey I don't have barcode scan event for it. The data goes into the computer just as if it were typed in on the keyboard. It is already written to accept keyboard data. It works in the same way like we copy plain text to clipboard and paste it to notepad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

form Catch keypress events on the keyboard. A barcode scanner sends a return character (enters) after the scanned code. Catch the whole thing, decide if its a barcode, and enter it into the required textbox?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171538%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You mean decides whether it is the barcode based on character length?

Comment: Well, thats what I would do. Catch everything, build a "buffer", after every add to the buffer, analyze it... Decide if its your barcode?

Comment: That's such a good idea. I marked your answer as a solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great. Glad I could offer some ideas. You will probably have to "make it work", but it should give you what your looking for... Cheers.

Comment: That one shouldn't be a problem. Easy Peasy. Cheers!